# How to prevent user changing URL <pk> to see other submission data Django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

I'm new to the web development world, to Django, and to applications that require securing the URL from users that change the foo/bar/**pk** to access other user data.

Is there a way to prevent this? Or is there a built-in way to prevent this from happening in Django?

E.g.:
`foo/bar/22` can be changed to `foo/bar/14` and exposes past users data.

I have read the answers to several questions about this topic and I have had little luck in an answer that can clearly and coherently explain this and the approach to prevent this. I don't know a ton about this so I don't know how to word this question to investigate it properly. Please explain this to me like I'm 5.

Comment: You did say 'ELI5'! The key word here is 'authentication'. You need to make sure the user is authenticated to access the resource (URL) in question. You can do this with various decorators, in the view function, with special middleware etc etc. The answers below are concrete examples of this. But 'authentication' will point you in the right general direction in the django docs.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways you can achieve this:

If you have the concept of login, just restrict the URL to:

```
/foo/bar/
```

and in the code, `user=request.user` and display data only for the logged in user.

Another way would be:

```
/foo/bar/{{request.user.id}}/
```

and in the view:

```
def myview(request, id):
    if id != request.user.id:
        HttpResponseForbidden('You cannot view what is not yours') #Or however you want to handle this
```

You could even [write a middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) that would redirect the user to their page `/foo/bar/userid` - or to the login page if not logged in.

Comment: How to check this thing in the update view of the class based view?

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using [django-guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2/) if you'd like to control per-object access. Here's how it would look after configuring the settings and installing it (this is from [django-guardian's docs](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2/userguide/assign.html)):

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> boss = User.objects.create(username='Big Boss')
>>> joe = User.objects.create(username='joe')
>>> task = Task.objects.create(summary='Some job', content='', reported_by=boss)
>>> joe.has_perm('view_task', task)
False
```

If you'd prefer not to use an external library, there's also ways to do it [in Django's views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test).

Here's how that might look:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from .models import Bar

def view_bar(request, pk):
    bar = Bar.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if not bar.user == request.user:
        return HttpResponseForbidden("You can't view this Bar.")
    # The rest of the view goes here...
```

Comment: how to do this thing in the class based views like update view for a particular entry

Answer (score 3):

Just check that the object retrieved by the primary key belongs to the requesting user. In the view this would be

`if some_object.user == request.user:
    ...`

This requires that the model representing the object has a reference to the User model.

Comment: This is checking the user object and another user object -- *not* the primary key of a user. You'd actually want to check `somePK == request.user.id`, right-o?

Comment: Internally the equality check may be against the primary key field of the objects, however it isn't necessary. some_object will have the pk passed into the view by the way.

Comment: How to check this condition in the update view in the class based views ?

Answer (score 3):

In my project, for several models/tables, a user should only be able to see data that he/she entered, and not data that other users entered.  For these models/tables, there is a user column.

In the list view, that is easy enough to implement, just filter the query set passed to the list view for model.user = loggged_id.user.

But for the detail/update/delete views, seeing the PK up there in the URL, it is conceivable that user could edit the PK in the URL and access another user's row/data.

I'm using Django's built in class based views.

The views with PK in the URL already have the LoginRequiredMixin, but that does not stop a user from changing the PK in the URL.

My solution: "Does Logged In User Own This Row Mixin"
 (DoesLoggedInUserOwnThisRowMixin) -- override the get_object method and test there.

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

class DoesLoggedInUserOwnThisRowMixin(object):

    def get_object(self):
        '''only allow owner (or superuser) to access the table row'''
        obj = super(DoesLoggedInUserOwnThisRowMixin, self).get_object()
        if self.request.user.is_superuser:
            pass
        elif obj.iUser != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied(
                "Permission Denied -- that's not your record!")
        return obj
```

Voila!

Just put the mixin on the view class definition line after LoginRequiredMixin, and with a 403.html template that outputs the message, you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want to look into user authentication and authorization, which are both supplied by [Django's Auth package] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/) .  There's a big difference between the two things, as well.

Authentication is making sure someone is who they say they are.  Think, logging in.  You get someone to entire their user name and password to prove they are the owner of the account.

Authorization is making sure that someone is able to access what they are trying to access.  So, a normal user for instance, won't be able to just switch PK's.

Authorization is well documented in the link I provided above.  I'd start there and run through some of the sample code.  Hopefully that answers your question.  If not, hopefully it provides you with enough information to come back and ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 2):

In django, the currently logged in user is available in your views as the property `user` of the request object.

The idea is to filter your models by the logged in user first, and then if there are any results only show those results.

If the user is trying to access an object that doesn't belong to them, don't show the object.

One way to take care of all of that is to use the `get_object_or_404` shortcut function, which will raise a 404 error if an object that matches the given parameters is not found.

Using this, we can just pass the primary key and the current logged in user to this method, if it returns an object, that means the primary key belongs to this user, otherwise it will return a 404 as if the page doesn't exist.

Its quite simple to plug it into your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from .models import YourModel

def some_view(request, pk=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(YourModel, pk=pk, user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'details.html', {'object': obj})
```

Now, if the user tries to access a link with a pk that doesn't belong to them, a 404 is raised.

Comment: *"the currently logged in user is available in your views as the property user of the request object."* -- But note that `request.user` can also be an `AnonymousUser` if the user is *not* logged in. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user)

Comment: 404 is for objects not found, not for objects that aren't accessible.

Comment: How to do this thing in the class based view -> update view. I am also facing the same problem in a update view of model . One user has created the article and other can change it by just changing the url. So how should I use this get_object_or_404() in the update view ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a recurring question and also implies a serious security flaw. My contribution is this:

There are 2 basic aspects to take care of.

The first is the view:

a) Take care to add a decorator to the function-based view (such as @login_required) or a mixin to the class-based function (such as LoginRequiredMixin). I find the official Django documentation quite helpful on this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/).

b) When, in your view, you define the data to be retrieved or inserted (GET or POST methods), the data of the user must be filtered by the ID of that user. Something like this:

```
 def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     self.object = self.get_object(queryset=User.objects.filter(pk=self.request.user.id))
     return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The second aspect is the URL:

In the URL you should also limit the URL to the pk that was defined in the view. Something like this:

path('int:pk/blog-add/', AddBlogView.as_view(), name='blog-add'),

In my experience, this prevents that an user sees the data of another user, simply by changing a number in the URL.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In django CBV (class based views) you can prevent this by comparing the
user entered pk and the current logged in user:

Note: I tested it in django 4 and python 3.9.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = your_model

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
        if kwargs.get('pk') != self.request.user.pk:
            return HttpResponseForbidden(_('You do not have permission to     view this page'))
    
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```