# How to improve the code on this safety check

Tags: python, django

I have some stores, which sells products (each store have it's own), and I was implementing a safety-check to prevent one store from messing around other store's products (in case the user is some kind of smarty-pants).

Let's say the user have permission to edit this product (Id 75)

http://localhost:8000/produtos/edit/75/

But not this one (Id 100)

http://localhost:8000/produtos/edit/100/

I was hoping to create a `_check_permission` method that could be used both in get and post, but seems like I still need to make call another `if permission is not None` to actually trigger message to the user.

Any suggestions on how to improve this? Seems like a lot of code redundancy, and not very pythonic (less code).

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')                                                            
class EditarProdutoView(View):                                                                                
    template = 'principal/editar_produto.html'
    def get(self, request, produto_id=None):                                                                  
         produto = Produto.objects.get(pk=produto_id)                                                          
         permission = self._check_permission(produto, request)                                                 
         if permission is not None:                                                                            
             return permission                                                                                 

         form_editar_produto = EditarProdutoForm(                                                              
             prefix='produto',                                                                                 
             instance=produto,                                                                                 
         )                                                                                                     
         return render(request, self.template, locals())                                                       

     def post(self, request, produto_id=None):                                                                 
         produto = Produto.objects.get(pk=produto_id)                                                          
         permission = self._check_permission(produto, request)                                                 
         if permission is not None:                                                                            
             return permission                                                                                 

         form_editar_produto = EditarProdutoForm(                                                              
             request.POST,                                                                                     
             prefix='produto',                                                                                 
             instance=produto,                                                                                 
         )                                                                                                     
         if (form_editar_produto.is_valid()):                                                                  
             revenda = Revenda.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)                                                 
             form_editar_produto.save(revenda, commit=False)                                                   
             return redirect("produtos")                                                                       
         else:                                                                                                 
             return render(request, self.template, locals())                                                   

     def _check_permission(self, produto, request):                                                            
         if produto not in request.user.produto_set.all():                                                     
             return HttpResponseForbidden("Produto indisponível nesta revenda.")
```

Comment: It could be improved with the use of [`Custom Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#managers). Check the documentation to see if that suits you.

Comment: You shouldn't really be defining `get` and `post` at all. What view class are you subclassing from? You should be using UpdateView, which takes care of almost all of the logic for you - and then this check should go into `get_object`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm extending just django generic View (updated the code). Use `get_object` you mean something like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25312900/1718174 ? In that case works, but I have another model which needs the same safety check and doesn't have a user attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure of the relevance of that linked answer, nor why you think a user attribute has anything to do with this. If you want `_check_permission` to be called automatically, you need to use the correct class - in this case, UpdateView with PermissionMixin. And as I said, you *shouldn't* define those get and post methods.

Comment: Consider if this would be a better fit for [CodeReview.SE]. Pretty sure it would be great there, but might want to read their help center to verify.